# Get all SharePoint groups via UserGroup.asmx

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

This really should not be difficult but damned if I can figure it out...

Using Usergroup.asmx I need to get a list of all the groups in a given site collection so I can loop through them and update the group owner depending on certain settings.

My problem seems to be (besides the fact that I cannot find any decent documentation or examples for using web services...the only samples I seem to find a contrived, useless example snippets) that there is no method for returning all the groups. The only one that comes close is GetGroupCollectionFromWeb() but that seems to only list a few groups.

Do I need to iterate through all the sites and sub-sites and for each of them make the method call? Then loop through each of those results and merge them into a single collection?

Thanks

- Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetGroupCollectionFromSite ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586945%28office.11%29.aspx

Comment: I feel sheepish...missed that one. Thanks.